# Simple percentage in Grafana using graphite

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have theese two events.

app.event.success
app.event.failure

I made this two lines in graphite

```
app.event.success.summarize(1h, sum, false)
app.event.failure.summarize(1h, sum, false)
```

Now I have the number os success and failures.

I tried this:

```
app.event.success.summarize(1h, sum, false).asPercent(#B)
app.event.failure.summarize(1h, sum, false)
```

And I received "0.4", but I want the inverse of this (99.6)

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`absolute(offset(x, -100))`

In this way, you can get the value of `|x-100|`. So you can combine your series with that to get 99.6 from 0.4.